# AJAX request through a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to achieve a delete link for comments on my site similar to how it's set up through twitter. So you'll never have to leave the page, and the div holding the comment will disappear. I know I have to do this through AJAX, which I'm still in the process of learning. This is what I have set up so far, but each time I click the link, nothing happens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete_post').click(function () {                       
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var data = 'id=' + id.val() + '&submit=yes';
        alert(id);
        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $url; ?>/process_form/delete_post.php",    
            type: "GET",        
            data: data,        
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {                
                if (html==1) {  
                    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';                 
                } 
                else {
                    alert("Post was not deleted");
                }              
            }        
        });
        return false;
    });
}); 

<a href="#" class="delete_post" id="dp<?php echo $comment["id"]; ?>">Delete</a>
```

Can you guys offer some advice on how to make this work? Thanks so much.

Comment: Anything in your console? Also, can you explain why you have `<?php echo $url; ?>` within your code? That will output it exactly as you see it since it's in double quotes unless I'm missing something.

Comment: what do you mean anything in my console? And I dont think the php code should affect anything. The whole page is php so it get's handled that way. I mean the <?php echo $url; ?> line works on my other ajax request to post comments.

Comment: Look in the dev tools of your browser. Anything output there would make this a lot easier to diagnose.

Comment: the url in dev tools is http://localhost/. I know for a fact the php there is correct, and everything else is working. It's not calling the jquery at all though since it never event displays that `alert(id);`

Comment: @AndrewKlatzke No if the code is inside a `.php` file it will not output `<?php echo $url; ?>`, the echo should work fine.

Comment: var data = 'id=' + id + '&submit=yes'; -- id.val() is returning null, use id to get the id

Comment: @MarcelGwerder I'd assumed this was external JavaScript - my fault for assuming.

Comment: @Alex You should really consider using the devtools of the browser (I suggest Chrome). At least the console for syntax errors and the network feature for checking XHR-Requests. Then I don't know if it's just wrong because of formating in your question but you are missing the `<script>` tag around your js.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder i do, i use chrome to check everything. Sorry I left out some things. it's fixed though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns a string.
Change the data part to this and it should work

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var data = 'id=' + id + '&submit=yes';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about Net in Firebug? You can get your post and output in there.  Any why not use the absolute url?

```
url: "mysite.com/process_form/delete_post.php",
```